# Upgrade of metadata is not happening in 2 nodes (mongo 2.6 to mongo 3.0)

Tags: mongodb, upgrade, sharding

Before nothing, thanks for give me your time reading this question!

I'm testing an upgrade from mongo 2.4 to version 3 (I have updated to 2.6 successfully). The issue is one step before upgrading the binaries, I want to have the validation of metadata for each node of my replica which is sharded as described in [upgrade sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/)

I have disabled the balancer and it seems that is disabled successfully:

```
mongos> sh.getBalancerState()
false
```

Sharding status:

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5eebbde828374ced0f5e432c")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "test_rs1",  "host" : "test_rs1/mongodb01:27017,mongodb02:27017,mongodb03:27017" }
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  no
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
        No recent migrations
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "test_rs1" }
```

As you can see the balancer is currently not running. Anyway, if I try the metadata upgrade is successfully for node 01 but not for the two others:

```
root@mongodb01 tmp]# ./mongos30Up --configdb mongodb02 --upgrade
2020-06-18T21:08:49.706+0000 W SHARDING running with 1 config server should be done only for testing purposes and is not recommended for production
2020-06-18T21:08:49.708+0000 I CONTROL  ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2020-06-18T21:08:49.708+0000 I CONTROL  
2020-06-18T21:08:49.708+0000 I SHARDING [mongosMain] MongoS version 3.0.15 starting: pid=11224 port=27017 64-bit host=mongodb01 (--help for usage)
2020-06-18T21:08:49.708+0000 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] db version v3.0.15
2020-06-18T21:08:49.708+0000 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] git version: b8ff507269c382bc100fc52f75f48d54cd42ec3b
2020-06-18T21:08:49.708+0000 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] build info: Linux ip-10-35-227-214 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2020-06-18T21:08:49.708+0000 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-06-18T21:08:49.708+0000 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] options: { sharding: { configDB: "mongodb02" }, upgrade: true }
2020-06-18T21:08:49.714+0000 E -        [mongosMain] error upgrading config database to v6 :: caused by :: balancer must be stopped for config upgrade
```

As you can see, is not working because of the balancer! same case for node 03...

Any clue?

EDIT: (Added bash script)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run the metadata for all DB's.

# VARS
MONGOS_BIN='./mongos30Up'
MONGO1='mongodb01'
MONGO2='mongodb02'
MONGO3='mongodb03'

#Give exec permission
`chmod 0100 $MONGOS_BIN`

## Start the metadatata upgrade.
$MONGOS_BIN --configdb $MONGO1 --upgrade
$MONGOS_BIN --configdb $MONGO2 --upgrade
$MONGOS_BIN --configdb $MONGO3 --upgrade
```

Comment: What is `mongos30Up`?

Comment: Hi @D.SM thanks for your comment! mongos30Up is the binary from mongos 3.0 rpm, I use that do to the metadata migration from v5 to v6 in all of the nodes of my replica set cluster.

Comment: I am not seeing any references to it in  a web search, it would be helpful if you posted that script in, say, a gist.

Comment: I have added in the main question :). Since is a small one, I think works better than a git repo

Comment: The script you posted calls `mongos30Up`, so it's a different script?

Comment: Oh, the first output that you have seen is the binary of mongos itself, I ran manually to get the errors. If you see, I'm calling Mongos30Up binary in all cases getting the same error.